# Why doesn't the constructor property resolve to the class's type in Typescript?

Tags: typescript, constructor

In the following code:

```
class A {
    static f() {}
}
const y = A;
y.f() // OK

const x = (new A()).constructor
x.f() // type error
```

`y`'s type is `typeof A`, but `x`'s type is the more general `Function`.

Why doesn't the `constructor` property resolve to the type of the class?

Comment: long answer: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/3841

Answer (score -1):

I think this is because of the `static` keyword. Putting your code into TS Playground as is compiles to this line `A.f = function () { };` without the `static` keyword it becomes `A.prototype.f = function () { };`

It looks like the `static` keyword attaches it to the class object and not prototype chain where it can be accessed from objects created by calling `new` on A.

Comment: I don't believe this addresses the question.